# FPGA: No user defined clocks warning

Tags: vhdl, clock, vivado

I am working with Artix 7 (xc7a15tftg256) in Vivado. In this project shows one warning message.

> [Power 33-232] No user defined clocks were found in the design!

I am using MRCC pin for system clock input.system clock usage is

```
if(rising_edge(clock)) then
    count := count+1;
end if;
```

Kindly provide the solution in this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more detail of the testing you have done. You can also check [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Based on your current question's wording, there is very little evidence of testing you have done.

Comment: I need the detail regrding,which pin is the system clock pin for Artix7 (xc7a15tftg256)?Kindly help me...

Comment: What's the name of your board? Please show us your ucf or xdc file.

Comment: I am not using any Development Boards.working for our custom board.my xdc file is given below.                                                                                                       set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 [get_ports clock]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 [get_ports input]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 [get_ports output1]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN N11 [get_ports clock]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN K15 [get_ports input1]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN C8 [get_ports output1]

Answer (score 2):

This warning means that there are no defined clock signals in your design.  In some cases Vivado will automatically constrain clocks for you, but if you are directly using an input pin for a clock, it will not.  Simply using a clock pin isn't enough since you can use the clock pins for IO as well.

What you need to do is provide a clock constraint.  An example is:

```
create_clock -period 4.000 -name myClock -waveform {0.000 2.000} [get_ports clock].
```

Where the period is the period of your input clock in nS, and the first number after waveform is the time of the rising edge, and the second is the time of the falling edge. The above example for a 250MHz, 50% duty cycle, 0 degree phase shift clock. The waveform argument is not necessary if you have a 50% duty cycle clock with no phase shift.